# How do I query for empty jsonb arrays in Postgres, Activerecord, Rails 5

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I have a `Post` model with the column defined by the following migration:

```
add_column :posts, :comments, :jsonb, default: []

add_index :posts, :comments, using: :gin
```

I would like to know the query to run so that I have a count of all the `Posts` which have the default, empty array as `comments`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Post.where("comments = '[]'").count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the json to string, and count the length. Empty json will return 2. This works for both {} and [].
E.g. To return non empty comment

```
Post.where("length(comments::text) > 2").count
```